# If-statement triggering despite not every condition met

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've got this if condition:

(48 - 57 are the typewriter numerics, 96 - 105 apply to the numeric keypad)

```
  if((e.ctrlKey && e.altKey) && ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58)) || (e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)){
      console.log(e.altKey);
  }
```

This is working well if i do not use the numeric keypad but the typewriter keys instead.

However, if i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + any number on the numeric keypad, the condition will trigger and output `false` to the console

How can that be?

Comment: You have an extra `)` after `< 58`

Comment: are you using keyup/keydown? from my knowledge, there are differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you mean?

```
(e.ctrlKey && e.altKey) && ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) || (e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106))
```

Comment: I should go to bed. Thank you.

Comment: +1 @Sprottenwels how about accepting the answer before going to bed :P

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
if  (
        ( e.ctrlKey && e.altKey ) 
        && (
            (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
            || (e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
        )
    )
{
      console.log(e.altKey);
}
```

You had a ) after < 58 wich was not on good place